# I have the following error when deploying my asp.net MVC4 project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

i have the following error when deploying my asp.net MVC4 project

```
public class Constante
{
    public static string path = "";
}
```

the error:

> An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Check the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. exeception details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: unknown host the error occur exactly in "Constante.path" line 11

Comment: Can you translate this?

Comment: And how are you deploying this?

Comment: deployed in windows server 2008 r2

Comment: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Check the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

exeception details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: unknown host

the error occur exactly in "Constante.path" line 11

Comment: What happens when you run locally from Visual Studio?

Comment: The error message likely has nothing to do with that bit of code.  It sounds like you have a problem in web.config.